# Refresh Angular 4 component depending on the current URL or on another component

Tags: angular

[image]

### The goal

The goal is to click one of the top users on the left and refresh the details about the user on the right. Meaning there has to be some form of communication between the two components.

What is the best way to do this and by best I mean most secure and most simple.

The point is not to just refresh the whole page, but just the individual detail component.

You can find the whole project on github. A link is provided at the bottom of this post.

### User-Dashboard-Component

```
     @Component({
selector: 'app-dashboard',
templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css'],
providers: [UserDetailComponent]
})

export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

users: User[] = [];

constructor(private userService: UserService, private userDetailComponent: UserDetailComponent) {
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.getUsers();
}

getUsers(): void {
    this.userService.getUsers()
        .subscribe(users => this.users = users.slice(0, 5));
}

public refreshUserDetailComponent(): void {
    this.userDetailComponent.refresh();
}

}
```

### User-Detail-Component

```
export class UserDetailComponent implements OnInit {

@Input() user: User;

constructor(private userService: UserService,
            private route: ActivatedRoute,
            private location: Location) {
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.getUser();
}

getUser(): void {
    const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.userService.getUser(id)
        .subscribe(
            user => this.user = user[0],
            error => console.error(error),
            () => console.log("getUser() loaded: ", this.user)
        );
}

public refresh() {
    this.getUser();
}
}
```

## [Git Repo for the entire project](https://github.com/AquaSolid/MEAN-stack-diversity)

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways you can interact between 2 different components is with the help of subject or behavioral subjects.
Using that, the data in the user-detail component will change based on the data in user-dashboard component.

Check it out in the below link

https://blog.cloudboost.io/build-simple-shopping-cart-with-angular-4-observables-subject-subscription-part-2-2d3735cde5f

Answer (score 0):

For this sort of problem you can use the powerful `RouterModule` combined with a nested `<router-outlet>` in `UsersComponent` for `UserDetailComponent`.

Everytime a user clicks on one of the Top Users the template inside the `<router-outlet>` changes. Your root component `UsersComponent` stays as it is.

In your `UserDetailComponent` you use the ActivatedRoute service to retrieve the parameters for the route. Subscribe to params, get the userId from the parameters and retrieve the user to display.

The big advantage of this approach is you can easily extend the functionality of your route with different [RouteGuards](https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards) for example retrieving the user before the route changes via `Resolver` or maybe you have a Form inside your `UserDetailComponent` and you want to notify your user of any unsaved changes before he leaves the route [CanDeactivate](https://angular.io/guide/router#candeactivate-handling-unsaved-changes)

I provided a small stackblitz demo:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kdywqe?file=app%2Fusers.component.ts

**users.component.ts**

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-users',
  template: `
    <h1>Users</h1>
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let user of users$ | async">
        <a [routerLink]="[user.id]">{{user}}</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <hr>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `,
  styles: []
})
export class UsersComponent  {
  public users$: Observable<string[]>;

  constructor(private usersService: UsersService) {
  } 

  ngOnInit() {
    this.users$ = this.usersService.getUsers();
  }
}
```

**user-detail.component.ts**

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-user-detail',
  template: `
    <h1>User Detail</h1>

    {{user | json}}
  `,
  styles: []
})
export class UserDetailComponent  {

  public user;

  constructor(private router: Router,
              private route: ActivatedRoute,
              private usersService: UsersService) {
  } 

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.pipe(
      map(params => params.userId),
      switchMap(userId => this.usersService.getUserDetail(+userId))
    ).subscribe(
      user => this.user = user,
      err => console.error(err)
    );

  }
}
```

**routing.module.ts**

```js
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'users',
    component: UsersComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: UserDetailComponent
      },
      {
        path: ':userId',
        component: UserDetailComponent
      }
    ]
  },
  { path: '**',   redirectTo: '/users', pathMatch: 'full' }
];
```